# JavaFX+WebView/Javascript : setTimeOut does not work call stack comes from Java

Tags: java, javascript, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I have a JavaFX application that loads my own HTML/JS application in a WebView. Depending on the event, I need to call Javascript from Java, and Java from Javascript.

Every is good when going from JS to Java but I've got weird behaviors when going from Java to Javascript.

- Here's, basically, how I setup the communication between the 2 languages:

_

```
var javaObjectInjected = typeof javaObject !== "undefined";

if(javaObjectInjected && !javaObjectInitialized) {
    jThalesEventBusInitialized = true;

    const jsAdapter = {
        publishToJs: onPublishToJs
    };

    javaObject.setJsAdapter(jsAdapter);
}
```

- My Java code will invoke the method `publishToJs` on the provided `jsAdapter`. This will result in the execution of `onPublishToJs`.

_

```
function onPublishToJs(topic, data) {
    alert('Yeah! We are inside JS'); //output_1

    setTimeout(
        function() {
            alert('inside setTimeOut'); //output_2
        },
        1000
    );
}
```

I do get output_1 but not output_2. It's like the callback on setTimeOut was discarded.

Are there any known limitations when invoking JS from Java?

Comment: This is pretty much a guess - try something other than `alert` in the `setTimeout` callback, such as logging something to the console.

Comment: JS console outputs are not forwarded to the Java console so I added FireBug Lite 1.2 to the <head> section of my HTML. In the setTimeOut callback I replaced alert('...') by console.log('...') and it does not change anything. Still no output_2!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored my code and instead of injecting `jsAdapter` to the Java world using `javaObject.setJsAdapter(jsAdapter)`, I exposed `jsAdapter` to Java as a new member of `window`.

With this new code structure, I got exceptions when invoking `jsAdapter` from Java because I was doing it from the `EDT` instead of the `JavaFX Application Thread`.

Eventually, I wrapped the `jsAdapter` calls in `Platform.runLater(() -> ...)` and that was it.

When working with Javascript loaded from a JavaFX WebView, make sure to always perform Javascript calls from the JavaFX Application Thread.